# How can I read a text file in the Resources directory using Swift 3 Playground?

Tags: swift3, swift-playground

I have a text file I created in the Resources directory of my Swift playground. I am trying to get the directory location of the "Resources" in the Playground during runtime, but it returns some other location that does not even exist.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
let dirLog = PlaygroundSupport.playgroundSharedDataDirectory
```

dirLog displays as:

```
file:///Users/ronaldo/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/
```

It seems that PlaygroundSupport does not have the methods I need to get this directory location. I saw some mention in another SE question and they used NSBundle class to get the files in Resources. But I can not find ANY NSBundle object to be used in Swift 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each Playground has its own Resources folder, and the actual path is hidden.

In Swift 3, you can get the files in the Resources folder by using `Bundle`:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")
```

The path of this Bundle URL contains the path to the current Resources folder.

---

You can also avoid using `Bundle` and drag & drop the file from the `Resources` folder to the Playground itself, creating a file literal.

For example, type `let url =` and drop the file, from the Resources folder, into the Playground just after the `=` sign.